# finalement vs enfin

Tags: synonymes

I am trying to understand the possible usages of "finalement" and "enfin".

According to 
https://french.yabla.com/lesson-Finalement-or-Enfin-805 , 
"enfin" describes a foreseeable outcome and "finalement" describes an unforeseeable one when both mean "finally".

Based on this and my research in dictionaries, I have concluded so far:

Finalement

- finally, in the end (unforeseeable outcome). Examples:

  - Finalement, il a quand même pu partir en vacances où il le voulait.
  - Malheureusement, tous leurs efforts n'auront finalement servi à rien.

Enfin

- finally, in the end (foreseeable outcome). Examples:

  - Enfin seuls !
  - Il a ecouté tout le monde et a parlé enfin.
  - Vas-tu enfin sortir de la salle de bains ? (expression of impatience)
- in short (summarizes previous topic). Example:

  - Il boit, il fume ; enfin, il a tous les vices.
- at least (expresses uncertainty). Example:

  - Enfin, ça, c'est ce qu'il dit !
- anyway (expresses change of topic). Example:

  - Enfin, je dois partir maintenant.
- oh well (interjection, expresses acceptance of an unpleasant fact). Example:

  - Enfin ! c'est la vie !
- oh come on! (interjection, expresses impatience/annoyance). Example:

  - ce n'est pas la même chose, enfin !
- after all (interjection, expresses that sth is true despite any indications or expectations of the contrary)

  - c'est son droit, enfin !

Is this correct? Are "finalement" and "enfin" interchangeable in any of these examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They quite overlap but while ***finalement*** is more neutral, ***enfin*** can have a positive meaning. I guess that's close to the unforeseeable/foreseeable description.

In your example, ***enfin*** seuls ! means being alone is a clearly a relief, same with *il a parlé **enfin*** (I'd rather say: *il a **enfin** parlé*) which imply everyone was looking forward to hear him.

On the other hand, ***finalement*** seuls ! is a little heavy, and might be used to just state we are alone after a long period and *il a **finalement** parlé* just means "he eventually spoke".

These adverbs are also not interchangeable in:

*Vas-tu **enfin** sortir de la salle de bains ?* (impatience, I want you to leave as soon as possible)

*Vas-tu **finalement** sortir de la salle de bain ?* (more neutral, do you plan to eventually leave the bathroom?)

The meaning is identical in ***enfin/finalement*** il a tous les vices.

***Finalement***, ça, c'est ce qu'il dit ! is not very idiomatic and the uncertainty meaning is missing.

***Finalement***, je dois partir maintenant doesn't mean *anyway, I have to leave now*, but I'm unsure either about this meaning in ***enfin***, je dois partir maintenant. I guess the context and intonation plays a strong role here.

Note also that a close expression, sometimes still disapproved (in vain), is emerging: *[**au final**](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/au-final)*. The reason is *final* being an adjective, *le final* is accused to break the grammar. My kids are constantly using it anyway, along with *grave* (for "a lot"), *trop* (for "very") and similar.

It replaces ***finalement*** (or ***à la fin***):

> **Au final**, il a quand même pu partir en vacances où il (le) voulait.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a related question. https://www.wordreference.com/fren/finalement says that "finalement" could mean "at last", but that English expression means that something *expected* happened after a long time (ref: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-last), which goes against the unexpected meaning of "finalement". Can "finalement" really mean "at last" ?

Comment: What is the "unexpected meaning" of *finalement*?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I meant that "at last" is *always* used with foreseeable/expected events, such as "enfin", and "finalement" is not, so I don't understand how "at last" could be translated to "finalement" (or vice-versa).

Comment: *Finalement* can actually be used with foreseeable (*prévisibles*) events too. The difference is not that the event is unexpected (*inattendu*) but that you are glad it happened with *enfin* (e.g. *enfin, il a réussi*) and neutral or sad with *finalement* (e.g. *finalement, il a perdu*).